# webmail is not displaying all To addresses while sending mail

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail, webmail

I could send mail to multiple ids by using JavaMailAPI.
     Added "To" addresses like ;

```
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("srikanth.c@domain.in"));
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("risto.j@domain.in"));
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse("vishnuprasad.v@domain.in"));
```

The mail has been sent to all specified To addresses.
        Outlook and Mozilla Thunderbird are displaying all To addresses. But why webmail is displaying only the last address added, in the above example, webmail is displaying only "vishnuprasad.v@domain.in" in To.

Answer (score 1):

It must be that specific `webmail` client's implementation. You can also observe that `Outlook`, and other mail client implementations differ to some extent. Say `GMail` header presentation is different from that of `Yahoo! mail`.

Check with your web mail client's FAQ and you may find a way to list all the mail recipient's addresses.

Comment: Ok, I will try. The link "View Message details" is showing all To addresses correctly in webmal.